# Listing all commits applied to a git repo between two dates

Tags: git

I need to find all the commits that were applied to my local copy of the git repo between two dates. The usual *git --log* commands won't do what I need. Here is my scenario in detail. Say on August 20, I need to list all commits applied to my local copy of the repo between August 1'st and August 15'th.

1. A commit another user made to his local repo in July but one that I pulled and merged into my repo during this period should make the list.
2. A commit that another user made to his local repo in this period but I did *not* merge into my repo till after August 15'th should *not* make this list.
3. Of course, all commits I made during this period should be in this list. Similarly, all commits made by other users to their local repos during this time period and also merged into my local repo during this period should be in this list. But this part is easy and this is what *git --log* does anyway. It's parts (1) and (2) above that are tricky.

**NOTE**: Any command that relies on commit dates alone cannot get this right. Most likely it will exclude the commits of type (1) and include commits of type (2). What I want is to include commits of type (1) and exclude commits of type (2).

Comment: How do you want to get the commits between 2 dates without using the commit's date?

Comment: What I really want is the date the commits were applied to my repo.  Not the date the commits were created.

Comment: you've got --merges and --no-merges flags to handle that.

Comment: Good point. I typically pull with --rebase though. So this does not solve my problem. Also note that I want *some* of the merges commits to actually appear in my list (if they were merged in the period of interest).

Comment: maybe what you want is a version's range, see if my edit is more helpfull now.

Answer (score 1):

from `git log --help` you can see this:

```
   --since=<date>, --after=<date>
       Show commits more recent than a specific date.

   --until=<date>, --before=<date>
       Show commits older than a specific date.
```

You've got also `--no-merges` flag to discard commit's applied because of pulls.

So, you can try:

```
git log --after=<date> --before=<date> --no-merges
```

But you might also try:

```
git log --graph
```

To see the full "tree" of commits.

**--EDIT**

Maybe what you really want isn't a date's range, but a version's range instead. See this from the manpage:

```
   <revision range>
       Show only commits in the specified revision range. When no
       <revision range> is specified, it defaults to HEAD (i.e. the
       whole history leading to the current commit). origin..HEAD specifies all 
       the commits reachable from the current commit (i.e.  HEAD), but 
       not from origin. For a complete list of ways to spell <revision range>, 
       see the Specifying Ranges section of gitrevisions(7).
```

So, you could pick the id of the commit you want to start the range and the id of the commit you want to finish the range which could be:

```
git log from_commit_id..HEAD
```

In case you want to see all the commits starting from one commit to where you are right now. Don't forget to use (or combine with) `--graph` flag which would give you the whole picture in any case.

Comment: This uses commit date. So this would exclude the commits in scenario (1) in my question since the commit date would be in July and include the commits in scenario (2) since the commit date would fall inside the period of interest. But what I want is to include the commits in (1) and exclude the commits in (2).